# Search For Each element in another table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a roster of employees in Table A, and their assigned accounts in Table B. I want to go through each employee in Table B and consolidate the accounts and send an email to each employee (not sure if I'm making sense).

I used for...each loop but can't progress further. Code below:

```
For i = 2 to rg.Rows.Count
   dumpData.Range("4:4").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Sheet1.Range("G"&row)
   
   For Each employee in dumpData.Range("P5:P" & lastRow(dumpData,"P"))
       'copy information and email
   Next
   row = row + 1
Next i
```

This led to some data being repeated (not consolidated) and going through the entire roster.

Also sharing an image of the tables:

[!Table and Roster[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFgeB.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFgeB.png)

Comment: There is no free code-writing service here. If you want to qualify your question as being about how to code you will need to add more focus to it.

Comment: Autofilter is not the easiest way to accomplish this.  You have to get VBA to deliver the Range of of visible rows, and then you have to loop through all the areas to get the non-contiguous rows.  Easier to just compare rg.Cells(i,16).Value = Sheet1.Cells(row,7).Value.